# Xbox One Right Trigger Not Working

Tags: input, unity-game-engine, gamepad, xbox-one

I have an Xbox One controller setup with Unity3d, and when I try to use the <kbd>RT</kbd> button nothing happens.

With the following setup, the <kbd>RB</kbd> button works fine:

[image: Fire1]

I have looked at [this](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Xbox360Controller) but setting that up doesn't make sense to me. I have tried `3rd Axis 0_10th` and I have tried `3rd Axis 0_1` but those are not valid. What is the proper settings for this to work?

Comment: Have you tried building your game, and then on the pre-game launcher's Input tab, double-clicking on the entry for Fire1 and pressing the trigger? This should let you see which axis it's using.

Comment: No I have not. I will give that a try.

Answer (score 4):

To the get the result I was looking for, I needed to set it up the following way:

[image: Final Result]

Then to get the button to work we need to use:

```
if(Mathf.Round(Input.GetAxisRaw("Fire1")) < 0){
    // Firing code here
}
```

instead of:

```
if(Input.GetButton("Fire1")){
    // Firing code here
}
```

Comment: For some reason, my left trigger worked, not the right trigger. then I tried all the axes but the right trigger didn't work at all. Is there a point I missed? note : my controller is logitech f710 and my right trigger  is working. :) EDIT: i just saw the other answers "Left and Right triggers now both use the 3rd axis"  just change the < 0  to > 0.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thanks for posting. I was having the same problem using a 360 wired controller in Unity3d. It looks like the Left and Right triggers now both use the 3rd axis (Joystick) with the Left generating positive (0 to +1) values and the Right trigger generating negative (0 to -1) values. This differs from all the documentation I was finding.